# Getting the last ng-repeat item after it has been orderBy'd

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I'm trying to generate a list of terms and their definitions, but place a header at the start of each letter section. IE

## A

> Apple

## B

> Banana

To do this, I have the following code:

```
<div ng-repeat="definition in definitions">
   <div ng-if="firstLetterOfTerm(definitions[$index])!=firstLetterOfTerm(definitions[$index-1])">
      <h1>{{firstLetterOfTerm(definitions[$index])}}<hr></h1>
   </div>
   <div>{{definition.term}}</div>
</div>
```

This works great if `definitions` is ordered. But if it isn't, this doesn't work. IE consider the list

```
["Banana", "Apple"]
```

Based on my current logic, this would produce the following list:

## A

> Banana

## B

> Apple

Thats because when I do `firstLetterOfTerm(definitions[$index])`, the `$index` points to the original, unordered list. Is there any way I can get it the proper positioning of the `$index`? Or perhaps a different way to architect this solution that produces the same results

**Note:** I do not want to presort the list beforehand as it can be quite large.

Comment: Why don't you use `sort()` in order to make sure that the elements are always ordered the way you want to?

Comment: @kidA If you would read to the end of my question you would find out.

Comment: Whether you presort it beforehand for your convenience, or have the `ng-repeat` sort it for you, your app is still sorting it in some way so it doesn't really matter if it is "quite large."

Comment: @rgthree Its not sorting it if I just take it in whatever order is given.

Comment: I 've read it and I don't understand what difference does it make if it is large.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg I'm confused. If `definitions` is not sorted in some way then the original and the repeated would be the same (and, thus, `$index` the same)?  I do not see how your second example is not `B > Banana; A > Apple` if your list is `["Banana", "Apple"]` and not sorted. Can you create a simple jsfiddle to show how do you get `A > Banana; B > Apple`?

Comment: Presorting actually makes *more* sense if it's large. Otherwise the array is sorted on every digest, I believe

Answer (score 0):

Do you expect your array to only contain a single instance for each letter? If definitions contains [apple, banana, avocado] won't it print the first letter for every string in the array:
a
apple
b
banana
a
avocado.

Also won't the first firstLetterOfTerm(definitions[$index-1]) return undefined as index 0 - 1 does not exist?
[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPOpLB)
`

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
angular.module('myStatefulFilterApp', [])
 .controller('personController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.definitions = ['apple0', 'banana0','apple1', 'banana1','apple2', 'banana2','apple3', 'banana3']

}])
.filter('startsWith', [function(){
  var start = function(array, letter){
    console.log(arguments)
    var newArray = new Array();
    angular.forEach(array, function(x){
      if (letter == x.charAt(0)) newArray.push(x)
    })
                    return newArray;
  }
  return start;
}])


 .filter('titleCaseFilter', [ function() {  
        var titleCaseFilter = function(array) {

        var newArray = new Array();
            angular.forEach(array, function(string){
            if (newArray.indexOf(string.charAt(0)) == -1)       newArray.push(string.charAt(0));
      });
  return newArray;
}
return titleCaseFilter;
}])



</script>
<div ng-app="myStatefulFilterApp" ng-controller="personController">

<div ng-repeat="definition in definitions | titleCaseFilter">
  <div>{{definition}}</div>
  <div ng-repeat="def in definitions | startsWith:definition">
    {{def}}
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Initially I did believe I was leaving a comment for some reason it became an answer... the initial question asked for a different way to "architect the solution" the link to codpen is just that.